# Force trigger resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to trigger the resize event by running this code:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

it only works when I run it from the browser console.

But when I fire it from an element onclick it doesn't work.

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){$(window).trigger('resize');});
```

[image: 1]

Comment: You must show the html

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/NR89G/

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually trigger browser events. It's a bad practice. Instead - just run the event handler function that is listening to the `resize` event.